# Access from the pod to a third-party server IP

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-networkpolicy, calico

I need to get access from the pod to the servers from the same subnet as the nodes of the kubernetes cluster (10.10.11.x), for example , to my gitlab server. I can ping onle k8s nodes from pods.
From the cluster node, the IP address of my gitlab server is available, I can ping, curl and nslookup, but from the pods when trying to execute ping or curl I have timeout error. But nslookup is working and can resolve IP address from pods. Also I can ping and curl IP address like google.com without problems.
I don't have any network policies configured, firewall is disabled on nodes and on my gitlab server.
I use Kubernetes 1.26 , calico 3.25.
The same problems with all external servers from my subnet, they are available from k8s nodes but not available from pods.
I've been struggling with this problem for a long time and I ran out of ideas.

1)I try to apply NetworkPolices, to allow access to gitlab servers. But it doesn't help, I can disable all traffic to internet, but can not open access to IPs 10.10.11.x.
Like this one

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-access-to-all
  namespace: gitlab
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gitlab-runner
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to: []
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
```

2)I tried to create Endpoints and Services for GitLab, but it also doesn't help

```
   apiVersion: v1
    kind: Endpoints
    metadata:
      name: gitlab-server
      namespace: gitlab
    subsets:
      - addresses:
          - ip: 10.10.11.2
        ports:
          - port: 80
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: gitlab-server
      namespace: gitlab
    spec:
      ports:
        - port: 80
          targetPort: 80
```

3)I test my calico networking using this
[guide](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/getting-started/kubernetes/hardway/test-networking) and everything looks good.

4)Check work of my k8s cluster? but didn't find any problems.